# force mysql cleint to start SSL/TLS immediately without server's plaintext handshake

Tags: mysql, ssl, proxy

I am trying to get HAProxy to do the SSL for a MySQL Proxy in front of a MySQL Server, however my problem is the mysql client is waiting for the [Initial Handshake Packets](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/internals/en/ssl.html) from the server, and the server (which is HAProxy) is waiting for the client to start a standard SSL handshake.

Is there a way to force the mysql client to talk SSL straight away without waiting for the normal plaintext handshake?

For architecture reasons I can't have the mysql client talk directly to the mysql server, hence the proxy and SSL.

Comment: Don't try to have haproxy terminate SSL. Just pass through.

Comment: As stated in the original post, for architecture reasons I can't have the mysql clients pass through to the server. This is because the proxy uses a LUA script to authenticate users that are not in and cannot be in the mysql server.

I have a solution though - it's to use an stunnel server to do the SSL between the client and haproxy. Users will have to point their clients at the stunnel listening port.

Answer (score 0):

Very old question of mine; the solution here was to use Stunnel as a client program to do the SSL for me.  There appears to be no way to get the MySQL client to talk native SSL first, it always wants to do it's own handshake.